# Magento just loading frontend

Tags: magento2, database, frontend-error, bin-magento

Anyone who experience that your frontend website is just loading just like this?

[image]

But the backend works properly. this is a Magento 2.2 platform. I am stuck on this please anyone can help me? thank you

Comment: There must be some js, CSS, fonts or image resources which are being called on the page which are not available.

Comment: How I will know sir? if I just see on my inspect elements are code without error. Can you please elaborate. Sorry im just new on this kind of error. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: From admin panel, enable logs via **`System > Configuration > Advanced (Developer) > Log Settings `**.

Comment: Then reload frontend and check **`/var/log`** folder in the document root of your installation. There must be some logs which will help.

Comment: if I will use this kind of line. 

php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

It crash my themes? I tried this code and it works but my website have been messed.